# Angular 2 Router: Add RouteParam without re-creating the component

Tags: angular

I have the following template:

```
<aside class="fv-right-sidebar" *ngIf="_routeParams.get('sidebar')">
  <fv-account *ngIf="_routeParams.get('sidebar') === 'account'" [accountId]="_routeParams.get('accountId')" (canceled)="closeSidebar()" (saved)="closeSidebar()"></fv-account>
  <fv-transaction *ngIf="_routeParams.get('sidebar') === 'transaction'" [transactionId]="_routeParams.get('id')" (canceled)="closeSidebar()" (saved)="closeSidebar()"></fv-transaction>
</aside>
```

When for instance adding an account, I do `this._router.navigate(['/Dashboard', {sidebar: 'account'}])`. However, the whole Dashboard Component get rebuild. I am looking for a way to set the query parameter without reloading the parent component. I tried using `location.go` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618463/change-route-params-without-reloading-in-angular-2). It does update the url, but not the `RouteParams`. I am looking for a way to set a route param without reloading the component. Any ideas if this is (already) possible?

It is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046485/add-parameter-to-angular-2-route-from-component-without-navigating) to use child-routes. However, since the sidebar is not always shown and I am unsure how to handle the inputs (accountId, transactionId) without having to rewrite the component to routeparams, I wonder if there is an easier way to update the RouteParams.

Thanks,
Robin

**Solution**

As [@günter-zöchbauer](/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer) suggested, the solution is to use `CanReuse` and `OnReuse`:

```
  routerCanReuse(nextInstruction:ComponentInstruction, prevInstruction:ComponentInstruction):any {
    return true;
  }

  routerOnReuse(nextInstruction:ComponentInstruction, prevInstruction:ComponentInstruction):any {
    this._routeParams = new RouteParams(nextInstruction.params);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [CanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html) and return `true`

```
class MyCmp implements CanReuse {
  routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) { return true; }
}
```

See also this discussion about when `CanReuse` works an when not https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7784